# Opencv C++ Recognize number

Tags: c++, opencv

this should be easy. I'm working on a Sedoku solver and I and trying to figure out how to tell which number I am looking at.

[image]

I am able to isolate the number as seen above. I just can't get any image recognition to work. I've tried Knearest and something called tesseract but to no avail. Any help?

Comment: Since you probably have just one font, with same size, for all numbers, you may use `matchTemplate` for each number, and keep the better response.

Answer (score 1):

for easy tasks like this, I would not recommend using something like tesseract. Just think about some simple trick way. For example, threshold it and count the black pixels and see what are the count for each number. of course this method will fail for 6 and 9 so you may cut the number into two half and count each one and compare.. and so on.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about a solution like that. The problem (and I know I didn't mention it in the description) is that it wont be scalable if I decide to use a different font.

Comment: yes of course it won't be... However, you may also look for Contour Analysis  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C